# Unable to call a regex method from another class method

Tags: ruby

So, I am new to ruby and am playing around with a simple scraping script. I wrote the following:

```
class Scrape

    def get_attribute(html, doc)
       doc.css(html).to_s.strip.remove_html_tags
    end

    public

    def remove_html_tags
       re = /<("[^"]*"|'[^']*'|[^'">])*>/
       self.gsub!(re, '')
    end

end
```

There are excluded methods but I followed my error back to this method and I keep getting the following whenever the get_attribute method is called:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `remove_html_tags' for #<String:0x007fcf42fd5610>
```

The only thing that works is when I use the gsub directly on the string:

```
def get_attribute(html, doc)
    doc.css(html).to_s.strip.gsub(/<("[^"]*"|'[^']*'|[^'">])*>/, '')
end
```

I've tried including this remove_html_tags method in a module as well but that did not seem to help. I can't figure out what I am missing, any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`doc.css(html).to_s.strip` is giving you an `String` instance, so you need to define the method `remove_html_tags` inside the class `String`. Currently it is the instance method of the class `Scarpe`, but you are calling it on the instance of `String`.

You could design your method as below :-

```
class Scrape
    def get_attribute(html, doc)
       string = remove_html_tags doc.css(html).to_s.strip
    end

    private 

    def remove_html_tags(string)
       re = /<("[^"]*"|'[^']*'|[^'">])*>/
       string.gsub(re, '')
    end
end
```

*Note:* If you don't want to expose `remove_html_tags` to the outside API, you should make it as `private` method, otherwise, make it `public`. In case of public, don't need to use the `public` keyword, by default all methods visibility falls into `public`.

Answer (score 2):

Whether you want to make use of method defined in class `Scrape` you should aknowledge ruby about:

```
#               string   call string’s method 
doc.css(html).to_s.strip.remove_html_tags
```

should be changes to:

```
# scrape    call scrape’s method 
self.remove_html_tags(doc.css(html).to_s.strip)
```

`remove_html_tags` itself should operate on string instance:

```
#                    parameter
def remove_html_tags input
   re = /<("[^"]*"|'[^']*'|[^'">])*>/
   # gsubbing parameter
   input.gsub(re, '') # using gsub not gsub! to _return_ correct result 
end
```

Comment: No need of `self`... :-)

Comment: I’m trying to explain things, not to obfuscate code to minimal count of letters used.